# Background on the ipad cut in half

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

Im trying to finalize this website, and somewhere during the time i was tidying up the code i messed up how the background looks on the ipad and iphone. It looks fine on all other browsers including the native android. theres a slight bug on firefox but im working that out now.
Website in question: http://morzi.com/constantine/

The bio page has a link to an ipad css but just ignore that i was just fooling around trying to fix the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where to begin, and I'm not sure what software you are using to code this but it's definitely not hand coded :s.

Anyways, your CSS is really screwed up.
Three solutions:

- Hand code the CSS and in this case you can play around with the background position which will align the background with the content, then you can redesign the picture to see the person on the left.

  ```
  background-position:top center;
  ```
- Restructure your HTML and CSS to have the website work in compartments:
  |aside|article|aside|

  ```
  <aside id='left'></aside>
  <article></article>
  <aside id='right'></aside>

  <style>
  aside#right,
  aside#left {
    width:5%;
  }
  article {
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;//centers the div
  }
  </style>
  ```
- Create a media type for mobile devices with specific width like so

  ```
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {//Iphone and below
  //css for mobile device
  }
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {//Ipad and below
  //css for mobile device
  }
  ```

I hope this helps and good luck to you :D